# How long will it take to get Google OAuth authorization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-fit, google-developers-console

I want to solve the problem appearing "Unverified apps" on my app because of google OAuth.

I received mail from google(API OAuth Dev Verification) as below.

[image]

So, I replied "Please proceed with option 1." amount two weeks ago.
But, there was no response..

What else can I do? Or is there only a way to wait?

Is there a way to ask Google separately?

Thanks

Comment: DaImTo answer is correct. But if you really net to get it verified at the soonest time possible, you can try to reach out to the support mail of the platform you are working on. *Maps, Fit, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Applying for verification is not a quick process.

Once you have completed all the requirements. You must then submit it for verification.  It can take anywhere from a week to a month, to get a response.

Yes the only thing to do is wait google will let you know if there are any issues with your application.

There is no direct contact as for more information.  If you haven't heard anything after a month you could send it again.

[image]

Just make sure you have meet all the requirments.

Comment: I haven't heard from them since 10/6 (2+ months ago). Anywhere I can go for help?

Comment: Check your email there should be a status in the developer console

Comment: I received their email a few days before my last submission on 10/6. I've changed the requested things and haven't gotten any emails since :/.

Comment: Email them back and let them know you changed something.  ask them to check again